# set the download speed with LWP - Perl

Tags: perl, wget, lwp

I am developing an application which download files from internet; the files are mainly in **ftp** servers, I am using `LWP::Simple` and the `getstore` function to retrieve the files. But I would like to limit the speed of download, like in `wget` ...

have you seen something similar to the `--limit-rate` from `wget` implemented within `LWP` or `LWP::Simple`??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your main concerns are FTP servers, maybe look at [Net::FTP::Throttle](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aFTP%3a%3aThrottle). You can set maximum rate in constructor.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such option.

If you use a callback to grab the response body, you could intentionally slow down the callback (using sleep()) when necessary to provide the desired rate.

Of course, you could also avoid LWP entirely. For example, you could and shell out to call `wget`, `curl` or whatever. You could also use another module such as [WWW::Curl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aCurl).

Update: Added last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

...Or you could use [LWP over libcurl](https://metacpan.org/release/LWP-Protocol-Net-Curl) :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use common::sense;

use LWP::Protocol::Net::Curl MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE => 10240; # 10 KB/s
use LWP::Simple;

getstore 'http://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.16.2.tar.gz' => 'perl.tar.gz';
```